# Downloading data using Github

Tags: git, excel, github, vba

Complete novice in this. All I want to do is extract these files into any .csv or .xls or similar format.

committee-membership-current.yaml

from https://github.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators/commit/e008a100629110f3ec6ccf1a30a9003ff285aaad#diff-5a41af9d9d109ba2feb0d5b2bc7c3573

&

https://github.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators

I see alot of code, where do I plug it in an run!? ha ha , you see I told you I was novice .

Surely theres gotta be a way one can press a button on that site to extract the information the code is relaying?

Or do I need an add-on on my browser to stick the code in to, and run myself and from where I will be able to edit it for Publically available repositories of data like this?

Any advice or information will be appreciated!

Comment: If you need to get few files, you can do that manually converting `yaml` to `csv` or `xlsx`. Particularly for your case file `committee-membership-current.yaml` is located by the URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators/master/committee-membership-current.yaml`, just open any online converter, e. g. [this one](http://convertcsv.com/yaml-to-csv.htm), paste the URL and save it as `xlsx` file.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thank you so much indeed !!! Wow !!! I didny know it could be so easy! you made it so easy !!! Thank you so much .

Comment: Thank you so much!! Thank you so much indeed !!! Wow !!! I didny know it could be so easy! you made it so easy !!! Thank you so much .

Comment: Oh Oh, it didnt work as I hoped it would. Firstly I get "invalid url" from step1 (option 2 - insert url). I enter https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unitedstates/congress-legi‌​slators/master/commi‌​ttee-membership-curr‌​ent.yaml. However once the url showed up as https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unitedstates/congress-legi‌​slators/master/commi‌​ttee-membership-curr‌​ent.yaml#L1, which didnt guve me an error. But still on following step2 and step3, at best the output it gave me only an exampl.csv file - only 4 rows. . Any further help? Any idea what basic step or thing im missing!?

Comment: ok, ive found http://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-json-xml-csv ... it looks better ...  but on loading my url, (yaml url) I get :

Comment: Error : Unable to parse.
Line : 1  <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: on copy path (yes I just noticed, on the girhub website there was a copy path button). and paste, it returns: Error : Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
Line : undefined  undefined

Comment: could it be only because its quite old? (last updated 29th January)? Could that be the only reason it is saying 1. 1. Error : Unable to parse.
2. Line : 1  <!DOCTYPE html> . Perhaps . Im still exploring

Comment: Check my answer, seems the link in the above comment is broken due to some chars, I fixed the link in the answer.

Comment: Thank you Very much omegastripes. Its working now!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get few files, you can do that manually converting `yaml` to `csv`.

Particularly for your case file `committee-membership-current.yaml` is located by the target URL

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unitedstates/congress-legislators/master/committee-membership-current.yaml

Then just open any online converter, e. g. this one http://convertcsv.com/yaml-to-csv.htm, paste the target URL,  save it as `csv` file, and open with Excel.

This question belongs to [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) in the first place.

Comment: @DavidWoolley if the answer helps, feel free to click to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Omegastripes. Answer works perfectly.